# Multipe Routes in Arrow API

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

Is there a way to declare multiple API routes from a single file in Arrow?

Example: Say you want to declare multiple endpoints for a user API:

- GET /api/user/:id
- DELETE /api/user/:id/delete
- POST /api/user

It would make sense to keep these in the same file since they are related and could share code, instead of splitting them into their own files.

I'm referring to [these docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Arrow_APIs).

Comment: I'm very curious about this as well

Comment: I am able to do so with Node.ACS published to arrow cloud. The new syntax of ArrowCloud is not straight forward for me at all. However, with Node.ACS published to Arrow Cloud lets you place all these backend functions in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment the only way to keep them in the same file is to use `ALL` as the method and then in the action use `req.method` to delegate to the right logic. E.g.:

```
..
  method: 'ALL',
  action: function(req, res, next) {
    switch (req.method) {
      case 'GET':
        ..
        break;
      case 'DELETE':
        ..
        break;
      default:
        return res.notfound(next);
        break;
    }
  }
..
```